# Swift App Project empty *.profraw or *.profdata after build and run?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have created a Swift App Project which only has a basic suite for a single-page application. And I add `-profile-generate` and `-profile-coverage-mapping`  two flags in Build Settings -> Swift Other Flags. However， it has not generated *.profraw or *.profdata file.

Meanwhile, I have created another Command Line App with Xcode, and add the same flags in build settings. Build and Run project, then I got *.profraw I want.

So, what can I do with Swift Single Page App to Generate the *.profraw file?